# Can I query an array of subdocuments by multiple parameters with mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find a user by their social services using service type and account id, but I don't know how to do this as a Mongoose query.

For example, how would I find this user, using Mongoose, if I have 'twitter' and '789DEF'?

```
{
"email":"me@domain.com",
"social": [
        {
            "service": "linkedin",
            "username": "Test User",
            "url": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/testuser",
            "accountId": "ABC12356"
        },
        {
            "service": "twitter",
            "username": "TestUser",
            "url": "https://www.twitter.com/testuser",
            "accountId": "789DEF"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query operator. Assuming you have declared a mongoose model (let's say `Users`), then something like this should work:

```
Users.findOne({
    social: {
        $elemMatch: {
            service: 'twitter',
            accountId: '789DEF'
        }
    }
}, function (err, doc) {
    // doc contains your user document
});
```

If what you need is only the relevant `social` subdocument, then you should also use the [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) projection operator:

```
Users.findOne({
    social: {
        $elemMatch: {
            service: 'twitter',
            accountId: '789DEF'
        }
    }
}).select('social.$').exec(function (err, doc) {
    // ...
});
```